# Reclassified slope raster attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have reclassified a slope raster in Qgis 3.4, but how to open or generate attribute table of that reclassified slope raster?

Slope ranges are on below picture.
[image: reclassify slope]

and my desired attribute table is as below:

[image: desired attribute table as]

Comment: Are you trying to have an attribute table for a raster? I don't think that's possible outside of an ESRI geodatabase raster.

Comment: Yes, and if a polygonized this reclassified slope, the attributes of converted polygons remains unclassified in qgis why?

Comment: that information is not stored in the raster. hopefully you kept track of it when you did the conversion.

Comment: @KapilDevAdhikari The only information that can be transferred to the polygon is the raster cell value.

Answer (score 1):

I used this procedure and I succeeded to reclassify slope:
1. Reproject (warp) the Dem `raster` from `WGS 84’ to`WGS 84/45N’
2. Use `Slope`algorithm of either Gdal or Qgis
3. `Reclassify by table’ from processing toolbox of Qgis Algorithms
4. Finally go to the properties of that Reclassified Slope and 
on Symbology select ‘singleband pseudocolor’ as rendering then, 
choose color ramp, 
And apply.
5. Result is: reclassified/modified raster cell as in esri.

Comment: Using of 'Raster pixels to polygons' from "Vector Creation Algorithms"  at Processing Toolbox can easily produce raster cell pixel into vector. This algorithm converts a raster layer to a vector layer, by creating polygon features for each individual pixel's extent in the raster layer. Any nodata pixels are skipped in the output.